# css make parent div 100% height and child scrollable

Tags: html, css, scroll, height, overflow

I am trying to create a site with a frame that fills all the vertical space, e.g. becomes smaller and overflowing content becomes scrollable.

html and body height are set to 100vh and all of the boxes parents are set to 100%. I have not found another method and this results in every single parent being 100vh and ultimately the site overflowing.

What am I doing wrong?
I feel like a am just missing the right "position: " attributes...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pastebook</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      height: 100vh;
    }
    /*central panel*/
    .central {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 100%;
      border: 3px solid blue;
    }
    /*central middle panel*/
    .middle {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 970px;
      height: 100%;
      border: 3px solid yellow;
    }
    /*content panel*/
    .contentPanel {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding-top: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      border: 3px solid lightgreen;
    }
    /*Clipboard Box*/
    .clipboard {
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 5px solid gray;
      font-size: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      padding: 5px;
      height: 100%
    }
    /*Example content*/
    .content {
      height: 100px;
      background: lightgray;
      margin: 5px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="central">
    <div class="content">
      central
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="content">
        middle
      </div>
      <div class="contentPanel">
        <div class="content">
          content
        </div>
        <div class="clipboard">
          <div style="height:400px; background: lightgray; margin:5px;">
            clipboard
          </div>
          <div style="height:400px; background: lightgray; margin:5px;">
            clipboard
          </div>
          <div style="height:400px; background: lightgray; margin:5px;">
            clipboard
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Reeeeally not sure what you're trying to do. However, you might wanna slap `box-sizing:border-box` onto all of your resolve-to-`height:100vh` elements. That'll make the non-margin space they eat take `100vh`, rather than their content alone.

Comment: In short: All elements except clipboard should take up exactely all vertical space, no more and no less, while overflow is managed by clipboard (the only place where it will actually occur).

Comment: Sounds like you want a `100vh` `flexbox` with `flex-direction:column` and `flex-grow:1`, or to be setting your div heights to `33.3%` instead of `100%`, and having clipboard be positioned outside of it/them, then. However I must ask *why* you want to do this? Not all viewports will have a large enough vh to contain all of your content, and the natural scrolling is done the way it's done for a reason. Like, this sounds like a UX nightmare in the making- makes me hesitant to really help.

Comment: If you're wanting a frame that takes up the entire page and all overflow content becomes scrollable, that's literally the default behavior of `body`...

Comment: Does not seem to work
It is supposed to be a simple full-height box for scrolling content divs

Comment: Riiiight because you nested everything. `33.3vh` instead of `33.3%` to trivially fix that issue. You'll also want to `box-sizing:border-box;` so borders and padding don't get in the way. Why is everything nested? And I'm still very confused by what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 3):

I tried some changing and this works

```
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
/*central panel*/
.central {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow:scroll;
}
/*central middle panel*/
.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 970px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*content panel*/
.contentPanel {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border: 3px solid lightgreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*Clipboard Box*/
.clipboard {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;      
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 5px;
}
/*Example content*/
.content {
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

tell me if something doesn't work or if I did something wrong :)
edit: okay so I looked into it a bit further and you can

- use flex boxes (which I do not like for no reason)
- javascript(which is an even worse solution but also works)
- css calc() function(I included this one at the bottom)

  - this will work better with a css addon that lets u use heights of
    other elements inside the calc() function

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*central panel*/

.central {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*central middle panel*/

.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(100vh - 55px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*content panel*/

.contentPanel {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border: 3px solid lightgreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*Clipboard Box*/

.clipboard {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 5px;
  height: calc(100vh - 165px);
}
/*Example content*/

.content {
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pastebook</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="central">
    <div class="content">
      central
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="content">
        middle
      </div>
      <div class="contentPanel">
        <div class="content">
          content
        </div>
        <div class="clipboard">
          <div style="height:400px; background: lightgray; margin:5px;">
            clipboard
          </div>
          <div style="height:400px; background: lightgray; margin:5px;">
            clipboard
          </div>
          <div style="height:400px; background: lightgray; margin:5px;">
            clipboard
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!
calc is exactely what i never knew i needed and it works great

Comment: Please mark my post as solution, It would help me reach more of these in need ☺️

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.central 
{
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: That's exactely NOT what I wanted. html. body, central, middle and contentPanel should fill the whole vertical space with .clipboard still being scrollable when overflowing.